# Windows 8.0 unable to display FAT32 external hard disk in “Computer”

Tags: windows, filesystems

My Windows 8.0 is unable to display my external hard disk which has important files and works well on Mac.  I know Windows uses the NTFS file system which is "more secure".  I need to format it as NTFS but I have important files on the hard disk which I want to copy on the windows machine and it's not even displaying on "Computer".

Disk management tells me it's working well though! So how did you go about fix this?

Comment: In `Disk Management` has your drive been assigned a letter?

Comment: NO bro, all I see is disk 1! Help me out please

Comment: And I can't assign a letter to it too! Very weird! I'm stuck now! it works perfectly on a Mac PC though

Comment: Can you create a volume?